# how do you have .net service listen on both ipv4 and ipv6

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding

I have looked a bunch over stack overflow and via google, but haven't found anything discussing the arcane configuration for .net services and ip stack selection.

Basically, I have a service configured as

```
  <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior"
    name="MyCompany.Service.MyService">
    <endpoint address="MyService" behaviorConfiguration="EndPBehavior" binding="netTcpBinding" bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_Default" contract="MyCompany.Service.IMyService">
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost" />
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:15030" />
        <add baseAddress="net.tcp://localhost:15035" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
```

My problem is when looking using netstat -nab

I see

```
 TCP [::]:15030
Can not obtain ownership information
```

and

```
  TCP 0.0.0.0:15035
[TestHost.exe]
```

So, one of the endpoints binds via ipv4 and one binds using ipv6.

The ipv4 of course will not respond to a ipv6 request, and the ipv6 bound one ignores ipv4 requests.

So, how can I get the service to bind such that all ipv4 and ipv6 addresses are listened to?

The current inconsistent behavior is giving a number of problems on Windows 7 machines.  Local traffic is tending to use ipv6 addresses while the routers in use only understand ipv4 so non-local traffic is using ipv4.

Any links to sites I may have overlooked explaining how to support both ipv4 and ipv6 would be appreciated.  Any magic changes to the configuration snippet so that both ipv6 and ipv4 would be supported by the service would also be greatly appreciated.